# Discord.py how to get a users' custom status?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a small bot for me and my friends to play around with it a little, but since I am new to python and especially discord.py, I have a small question. How do I get the custom status from a specific user? I've only seen how to get the game activity or the online status and after quite some googleing I still haven't found what I'm looking for. I hope you can help me!

Comment: Do note that to get the custom status you will need the [presence intent](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#privileged-intents)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member) class, you can see that member has attributes `status` & `raw_status` so you can chose the prefeded one by writing

```
status = member.status
raw_status = member.raw_status
```

You can also use `activity` or `activities` for user's rich presence/activity

```
activity = member.activity
activities = member.activities
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the activities of a `Member` via [`Member.activities`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.Member.activities). Whether it is a `CustomActivity` or anything else. Every activity that a `Member` has will shown up in the [`Member.activities`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.Member.activities). But unfortunately, we can't access a `User`'s activities.